Lamppost replacement with different size base
I am trying to replace a set of lampposts the old owners installed. The new ones are about a 10in diameter but the old was about 14. Looking at the old it almost looks like there is a riser/adapter there. The manufacturer of the new only has the 10in. Anyone seen this before? https://imgur.com/gallery/jL7d45g

Would it be feasible to clean up and reuse the old pedestals?

What is your actual question?  There are hundreds if not thousands of lamp post designs.  So I haven't seen the type you have...but I have installed a few different types.  However you have not asked a question about installing any post.

The old pedestals are falling apart.

@RMDman The question is whether there is a place that sells the risers or pedestal to expand the diameter of the base. I included a link to a picture of both new and old.

the answer is there almost certainly is, but shopping questions are off topic.

The existing lamp looks like a 2-piece—base unit with pole bolted on top.  Are you sure the new lamp can't just sit on top of the existing base, or get a new base that matches the new pole?  Can you give us details of the new base?  Is the existing base in poor shape, or is it just the pole that is?

The existing base is in bad shape and does look like two parts. If I take one apart I could confirm whether I could attach to it but would not be able to do it permanently since it is in bad shape (I am also missing two of the four). The new base in the picture looks like the old on top of the riser portion. Very similar.
